# Laravel 5.2, three way many too many

Tags: laravel-5, many-to-many, pivot-table

I want to do the following.

I have three models: `User`, `Business`, `Role`

They are connected as follows: Users can have many roles, and belong to multiple businesses.

Roles are predefined.

I want that each user can have different roles in different businesses.
For example, in business1 the users has role `sales manager`, but in business2 he has role `director`. User can have multiple roles on same business.

`User` model:

```
public function businesses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Business')->withTimestamps();
}
```

`Business` model:

```
   public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Business')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Pivot table:

```
    Schema::create('business_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->integer('business_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
    });
```

I add the `User` to the `Business` as:

```
$user->businesses()->attach($business_id, ['role_id' => $roleId]);
```

This should add the row in pivot table as: ['1','2','3'].

My questions are:

- Is this the right way to do this?
- How do I proceed with detach method?
  `$user->businesses()->detach($business_id)->where('role_id',$role_id);`
  This is not the correct syntax but something like this. If the user has two roles in a business (for example: 'director' and 'sales manager') on detach I want to remove just one of the roles (for example: 'director') and not all of them. I believe that running `$user->businesses()->detach($business_id);` will detach all roles.
- Is there a way to use the `sync()` method with this?

Comment: Use a scope to filter the right roles for that user and that business. Your relationships are good I think

Comment: Hey @MikeMiller, in the end I figured it out, this pointed me in the right direction, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with something like this below. It wasn't tested because my code is a bit more complicated so please notify me if you see any mistakes:

USER MODEL:

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->withTimestamps();
}
public function businesses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Business')->withTimestamps();
}
public function businessesAdmin()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Business')->withTimestamps()->wherePivot('role_id', $role_id = 'whatever_is_your_businessAdmin_role_id');
}
```

USER CONTROLLER:

```
function addAdminRole(Request $r) {
    //get the user_id and business_id from the $r
    //define $businessAdminRole_id
    $user->businesses()->sync([$business_id => ['role_id' => $businessAdminRole_id]]);
}

function removeAdminRole(Request $r) {
    $user = User::findOrFail($request->user_id)
    business = $request->business;
    $user->businessesAdmin()->detach($business_id);
}
```

I hope I didn't miss anything.
I lost too much time on overthinking this...
Hope it will help someone.

If you need more code please ask while its still fresh.